# An Enquiry Concerning the Mean of a Truncated Exponential Distribution

Tags: probability, integration, stochastic-processes, expectation, poisson-process

**The Statement of the Problem:**

Let $ \{ N(t), t \ge 0 \} $ be a Poisson process with $\lambda = 1$. Define

$$A(t) =
\begin{cases}
t  & \text{if $N(t) = 0$} \\
t-s_k & \text{if $N(t) = k, k \ge 1$.}
\end{cases}$$

Find the distribution of $A(t)$, then find the mean of $A(t)$.

**SOLUTION**

$$ \mathbb P \{A(t)=0 \} = \mathbb P \{N(t)=0 \} = e^{-t} $$

and for $0 \lt x \lt t$,

$$ \mathbb P \{A(t) \gt x \} = \mathbb P \{N(t) - N(t-x) =0 \} = e^{-x}. $$

So the distribution of $A(t)$ is truncated exponential; that is,

$$ A(t) \sim \min\{Y, t\} $$

where $Y \sim \text{Expo}(1)$ and

$$ \mathbb P \{A(t) \gt x \} =
\begin{cases}
e^{-x}  & \text{if $0 \le x \lt t$} \\
0 & \text{if $ x \ge t$.}
\end{cases} $$

Now, the mean of $A(t)$ is

$$ \mathbb E \{A(t) \}  = \int_{0}^{t} \mathbb P \{A(t) \gt x \}dx = \int_{0}^{t} e^{-x}dx  = 1 - e^{-t}.$$

**My Question:**

Why isn't the mean

$$ \mathbb E \{A(t) \}  = \int_{0}^{t}x \mathbb P \{A(t) \gt x \}dx = \int_{0}^{t} xe^{-x}dx?$$

As in, why isn't it computed the usual way we compute expectation by throwing an additional "$x$" in the integrand with the pdf?

Comment: You introduce $s_k$ and don't use it at all. Check the definition.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expected_value#General_definition The solution provided is using the so called tail sum / layer cake representation. Which formula to use depends on which one is more readily available and easy to integrate. In your case obviously the survival function is easier. And also in your question your formula is wrong - if you insist to "throw" an x inside the integrand, you will need to use the pdf, but no longer the survival function.

Comment: Right, of course. It's the survival function in there not the pdf; that somehow slipped by me. But, this "layer cake" approach is new to me and seems quite useful, so that's good to know! Thanks.

Comment: Unrelated to the question you ask, but the 1st statement of the solution seems wrong and unnecessary.